# Best way to have an updatable object in a partial?

Tags: ember.js

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eyatORO/2/)

I am new to ember.js and trying to figure out the best way to accomplish an updatable list.

The list, inside a partial, is updated when a list item from another object is clicked. Is it better to save the clicked(chosen) items in a separate model? or is it better to use an array in the controller as I was trying to do in the above jsbin?

In either case, how is it accomplished? In my above attempt the totalValue seems to update fine, but the array does not which makes me think I was going about it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chosenList is an array and ember array has it's own api methods in order to inform observes...
With this variation in your code, the property updates http://jsbin.com/eyatORO/3/edit

```
this.get('chosenList').addObject({
  title:item.title,
  value:item.value
});
```

Good Luck